Twisting global sections of sheaf with line bundle $H^0(E,\mathcal{O}_E)\otimes L_x^{\otimes k}\cong L_x^{\otimes k}$
This is from the proof of the Kodaira embedding theorem (p.249 Huybrechts's Complex Geometry).
By $E$ is denoted the exceptional divisor of the blow up of $X$, $L$ is an ample line bundle and $L_x$ the fiber over $x$.
According to lemma 2.3.22 $\mathcal{O}_E$ is the structure sheaf of the divisor $E$.
So technically $\mathcal{O}_E$ is not a vector bundle, but I know that vector bundle can be viewed as locally free coherent sheaves.
$\bullet$ Is the isomorphism given by using $H^0(E,\mathcal{O}_E)\cong \mathbb{C} $ and so $H^0(E,\mathcal{O}_E)\otimes L_x^{\otimes k}\cong \mathbb{C}\otimes L_x^{\otimes k}\cong L_x^{\otimes k}$ ?

That isomorphism makes no sense, the left hand side is a line bundle but the right hand side is a $\mathcal O_{X,x}$-module.

@red_trumpet maybe I have some typos. Everywhere should be $L_x$ the fiber instead of $L$.

Now your argument looks fine to me. I didn't read up on the context but note that you need $E$ to be connected for $H^0(E, \mathcal O_E) \cong \mathbb C$ to hold. I think this should hold if the subscheme which was blown up is connected.

@red_trumpet Thank you the conformation. I was just a little confused about $E$ been a divisor since we can view it as a sheaf it's okay.
